# Null Reference Exception was unhandled in C# VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ocr

I'm very new with VS2008 and I've been looking everywhere but couldn't found any solution to my problem. Here is the code:

```
 private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (!msgfilter)
                {
                    this.Enabled = false;
                    msgfilter = true;
                    Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
                }
                tw.Acquire(); <-- This is where the error shows
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well what exactly is `tw`, how do you create or initialize it ?

Comment: what is tw ? and where is it declared

Comment: what are you trying to do here?.. Null reference comes if `tw` is Null. let us know from where `tw` is coming?

Comment: This is the related code:
private bool msgfilter;
private Twain tw;
private int picnumber = 0;

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
if (Twain.ScreenBitDepth < 15)
{
MessageBox.Show("Need high/true-color video mode!", "Screen Bit Depth", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
return;
}
MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
Application.Run(mf);
}
private void selectScannerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
tw.Select();
}

Comment: please post full code

Comment: Declared. 
private Twain tw;

Comment: does `tw.Select();` inside `selectScannerToolStripMenuItem_Click()` method works for you? I doubt it won't work as well, because there is no instances for it!. Modify this line `private Twain tw;` as `private Twain tw = new Twain()`, and it you may see it working..

Comment: Thank you very much Deepak Raj. It's working perfectly now.
But I curious about something.....

Answer (score 2):

Your tw variable was not initialized. It has it's default value null. And you cannot call a method (.Acquire() ) on null, you need a real object created.

Somehwere in your code, you are missing the line

tw = New ???()

where the qeustion marks need to be replaced by your class type.

Comment: This is how its looks like:
-> private Twain tw;

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you have a null reference exception, the most useful things to do are

- Running your code with the debugger, to see which object was null (I guess in your case it will be `tw`)
- Checking the stack trace of the exception, which will give you more details about where the error occurred, who was the caller etc

Comment: tw.aquired() is to call installed TWAIN devices. It's working well in other form.